# Solid Angles: 3D Polygon inside a sphere

Tags: geometry, spheres, polygons, solid-angle

My propositional logic about the topic is following and My question is the way to prove this:
If two or more points(vertex) of a 3D polygon share the same solid angle, then those points are on the same sphere.

Please note that solid angles that I mentioned is originated from individual points, not the one common coordinate. For instance, the solid angle of 12th point on the below picture is calculated by three vectors from 12 to 23, 5, and 24.

[image: 3D Polygon that has 84 points]

The polygon on the above picture has 84 points. I highlighted(yellow) points that has the same "solid angle". And I think they are on the same sphere that is smaller in size than the polygon. But I am not sure where to start to prove it.

Comment: You highlighted some 10 points or so; what is it that they all share and the others don't?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. 10 points share the same solid angle and other has different angles. So I think those 10 points are on the same sphere since they have the same solid angle.

Comment: Then I completely fail to understand what do you mean by **solid angle**. Is it that each of these points is a junction of 3 hexagons? Then I believe there must be more than 10 of them.

Comment: I am very sorry for your confusion. More clearly, each point has its own solid angle made by three nearest points. For example, the point 5 (one of the highlighted points) has a solid angle made by the points 12, and 3, and 6 and they including 5 shape a tetrahedron.

Comment: OK, things are getting clearer now. How do you know that these 10 points have the same solid angle? Are all pentagons equal? Are all hexagons equal? Are they all _regular_?

Comment: Thank you so much for your time sir or madam, I know the angles from position vectors of all points. As you can see, at the center, there are coordinate axes (x,y,z).

Comment: For your information, actually there are more points' groups that share the same solid angle. The picture is one group of them. However, notice that there is no more point which has the same angle with those highlighted point on the picture due to a lack of symmetry of the structure.

Comment: OK, now what prevents me from taking any point **together will all its neighbors** (12, 5, 23, 24) and moving them all by some vector? The solid angle will remain the same, but the point 12 will leave the sphere.

Comment: I think it is better to explain why I am trying to find out the relation. The picture above is actually a real molecule which is C84. So any transition is infeasible unless you destruct the structure. 84 carbons shapes a closed shell. If the highlighted carbons make a sphere, I can be sure there is a spherical symmetry around the highlighted carbons. And then I can dramatically reduce much computational time. Of course, I can check the symmetry with some calculation but I need to be sure mathematically correct that points that shares the same "solid angle" in a polygon shapes a sphere.

Comment: Well, I fail to see how this helps. **Geometric symmetry** reduces you CPU cost all right, but you seem to have none or very little of it (unlike C60 or other highly symmetric fullerenes). A chance **coincidence** (like being at the same distance from the center) does not help at all. So what if they are on the same sphere? That doesn't make any elements of the Hamiltonian vanish.